# Is there a Scala stdlib function to transform a Stream[Byte] into a Stream[InputStream] where each InputStream is N metabytes in a purely lazy way?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to upload a large Stream[Byte] to S3 as a single file using the Multipart Upload API. I need to write a function `Long => Stream[Byte] => Stream[InputStream]` where long describes the size of the InputStream. I'm trying to do this lazily such that I don't need to hold the entire InputStream in memory at once.

Is there a function in the stdlib to do this?

Comment: So you want some kind of "grouped" feature on `Stream` and build one `InputStream` for every group of `n` `Byte`s?

Comment: Not sure about the standard library but this sounds like a perfect use case for Akka Streams. Which might even be able to handle the upload to S3 by itself (not sure if Alpakka S3 connector is able to handle this scenario).

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes that's the intention of the function. Unfortunately I can't pull in Akka for this.